# ASP.NET's ClickOnce: what's the suffix-less .application file?

Tags: asp.net, clickonce

I suffer from `InvalidDeploymentException` which apparently occur when there is something wrong with my manifest files. I look into the folder where my application is published but there are always more than one manifest file (.application) in it.

One is with the version suffix, and the other is without the suffix. As far as I see, the contents of both files seem to be identical, so why the one without the version suffix is ever automatically generated? I can't find info on the mechanism behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.

`YourApp.application` is a deployment manifest and `YourApp_#_#_#_#.application` is a backup file of each version's deployment manifest. When some troubles happen, we can manually replace `YourApp.application` by `YourApp_#_#_#_#.application`, and web browsers always look at the former file.